# Why does Webpack output weird comments before each line?

Tags: webpack

What's with the leading /******/ comments WebPack generates in output? Is it to mark WebPack related code, or is there more to it?

Here's a simple output example:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    document.write('I think it works!');


/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

Comment: Yes - it marks webpack related code.

Comment: It kind of baffles me that such an obscure convention has been accepted to readily.

Comment: Don't you just love how our community keeps jumping on the hype train?

Answer (score -1):

Webpack gives your modules and chunks ids to identify them. To minimize your script, it is recommended to use the UglifyJs plugin (`new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()`).

I recommend to read the [optimization](https://webpack.github.io/docs/optimization.html) page, where you can find information about how to minimize and further optimize your script.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.